# Send commands to another program from Python script in Real-time

Tags: python, real-time, communication

So I have this python program that detects my face and checks whether I'm moving left or right (using opencv). I have another program (car race) which needs commands left and right when I move my head to that direction. The car should turn in the direction I turn my head.

I need to send commands to that second program over real time(second program is a small javascript file). I can rewrite it in python if required.

I have used pywin32, but it doesn't work in realtime. The whole program gets stuck when I run it. This is what I did:

```
import win32com.client as comclt
wsh= comclt.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
wsh.AppActivate("Notepad")
if head_is_left():
    wsh.SendKeys("{LEFT}")
```

I am working on windows using python 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the two scripts into 2 functions in the same script, and then use the multiprocessing module to run them simultaneously and add the direction to a list or variable.

These are some good website to understand and use the multiprocessing module:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html
- https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/

To do this you will have to rewrite the second program in python though.